# How to prevent code from showing an error after getting the value of model instance is NULL in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am writing my views.py, in which i need to get the model instance by following code:

```
model_instance = AlertCount.objects.get(user=request.user.username)
```

But at the first time after running `python manage.py syncdb`. The field of table is initially `empty`. So it shows this error

```
DoesNotExist: AlertCount matching query does not exist
```

It should be obvious. But according to my views.py method, Event if this error occurred it continue to execute the method after passing `0` to all of the fields to this model instance.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but you shouldn't use 'user.username' as the foreign key, since a username can change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to do something like this:

```
try:
  model_instance = AlertCount.objects.get(user=request.user.username)
  # Set your local fields here
except AlertCount.DoesNotExist:
  #Set your local fields here to zero
```